# Remove unused localizations from APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, localization, proguard

For an Android app with no localizations (default language only), how can you exclude localizations from Gradle dependencies?

Background: The app is a line-of-business app for which the only language that needs support is US English. The app includes `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0` for push notification support. The GCM library includes localizations in 73 languages. I'd rather they not be included. That keeps the APK smaller. Additionally, if a user is running with a non-English language, I don't want the experience to be a mix of English and localized text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In build.gradle, add [`resConfigs`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking#TOC-Res-Configs) to limit the languages:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // other configuration here
        resConfigs "en"
    }
}
```

Comment: for multiple resConfigs "en", "fr"